# Hide particular day from google calendar in Android

Tags: android

How can i make particular day deselected in google calendar.On click of button i open date picker dialog to select date.here i need, user can able to select only Sunday. Remaining days should be unselectable with transparent color. how can i do this.

Code which i tried:

```
         {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        if (day !=Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,day);

        }

         dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, 
         month, day);
         dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + 
         (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        dialog.show();

       }


      public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new 
       DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
        TextView tv = (TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);

        tv.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                .append((month + 1)).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));

    }
};
```

Comment: You'll probably have to override DatePicker, look at it's source and try to add this functionality. Then use a regular Dialog, AlertDialog or Fragment Dialog to show this view.

Comment: @RobCo supposed i used Dialog,but the problem is how to hide particular day  here all day except sunday in google calendar.So that user can only select that day means "Sunday" .